# Extract a table out of data frame in pandas based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here are the column names of the pandas dataframe

```
result.columns.values
```

> ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F' 'G' 'H' 'I' 'J']

When I try to filter out using

```
filtered = result[(result['A'] <result['C']<result['D']) and (result['F'] <result['G']<result['I']) ]
```

I get this ValueError

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What's going wrong?
How do I correct this

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need to structure like:

```
filtered = result[((result['A'] < result['C']) & (result['C'] < result['D'])) &
                  ((result['F'] < result['G']) & (result['G'] < result['I']))]
```

#### Example

```
import numpy as np

columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
np.random.seed(0)
result = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 101, size=(100, 10)), columns=columns)
result.head()

filtered = result[((result['A'] < result['C']) & (result['C'] < result['D'])) &
                  ((result['F'] < result['G']) & (result['G'] < result['I']))]
filtered
```

[out]

```
     A   B   C   D   E  F   G   H   I   J
7   35  11  46  82  91  0  14  99  53  12
28  34  69  53  80  62  8  61   1  81  35
```